# Optimal method to test an external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, macos

I've got an HFS+ formatted external drive that is starting to act a bit funny, mainly causing my mac mini (finder) to freeze up on occassion when accessing it.

Fearing imminent failure, what is the most comprehensive way to determine the health of the physical drive and the file system?

Verify in Disk Utility indicates the disk is fine, but weird behaviour would indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's Disk Utility doesn't have false positives but it can miss some errors.

Although it's not cheap [Disk Warrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/) is **magic** for these sort of problems, in my experience it's fixed all non-physical-damage errors that I could throw at it.

If you're not keen to spend money, and if you've got the hard disk space, copying the contents off, repartitioning your external drive and copying back on on might clear up your problems. Copying the whole disk's contents (starting with what is most valuable to you, in case it dies while you're copying) is probably a good idea anyway, in case your disk is on its death bed.

Comment: Will Disk Warrior scan the disk to detect for errors first?  I'm not even certain that the disk is defective..just trying to be preemptive

Comment: Is it safe to Rebuild directories and/or Check Files/Folders even if the drive doesn't appear to have any issues?

Comment: Yes on both counts - it's safe to run on a healthy drive.

Comment: Any experience with [Drive Genius?](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/drive_genius.php)

Comment: Not me sorry! It looks more like a defrag than a disk checker.

Comment: Looks like the drive has bad sectors, which I understand is a physical issue.  Any suggestions for getting the data off in the most comprehensive way?  I'm currently trying to image it using Drive Genius...

Comment: I haven't used d/g but it should work. Get your critical files off first- bad sectors shouldn't indicate iminent doom but it's better to be safe than sorry!

Comment: @JoshNewman you can use the `dd` terminal command. It is free, already bundled with OS X, and probably the *best* cloning tool: http://serverfault.com/q/4906

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **Drive Genius** allows to check surface for bad sectors even in demo mode:

[image: Drive Genius screenshot]

There is also option to perform an "Extended Scan" which checks disk for read and write ability of a disk (burn-in test for drives).

It also supports block remapping "Spare bad blocks" option but you should **backup your data** before doing this.

There is [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46785/disk-diagnostic-and-repair-utility-for-mac-that-works-with-all-kinds-of-storage) where some more utilities may appear in answers.

It's hard not to mention [MHDD](http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/) which gives much more information about what's going on with you disc while it scans it (instead of showing nice visualisation):

[image: MHDD in work]

Here is video from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLQjpG-Gspw&feature=related).

Comment: A "surface scan" is not a reliable way to diagnose a disk. It may be as ineffective as using S.M.A.R.T. analysis (which is probably the poorest way to isolate hardware faults). Additionally, block remapping should only be used immediately before you try and move the data from the drive, possibly preventing data corruption. Don't rely on it to restore your hardware to any reliable state. It is always best to download the utilities provided by the hardware manufacturers. They require windows, but since the drive is portable, shouldn't be a deal-breaker.

Comment: You are absolutely right

Comment: I ran the DriveGenius 4 demo tonight, and it would not let me run the "Physical Check" without buying a $99 license.  The Extended check gave me an estimate of 41 days 16 hours to check a 2TB drive, but it was also unavailable in the demo.