# Disk diagnostic and repair utility for Mac that works with all kinds of storage devices?

Tags: software-recommendation, disk-utility, repair, macos

There are some nice and useful utilities for testing disks for bad blocks like [MHDD](http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/), [Victoria](http://www.mhdd.ru/download.html), [HITACHI Drive Feature Tool](http://www.hitachigst.com/support/downloads/) etc. But these utilities have some limitations.

For example, [MHDD](http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/) is the best utility I've ever seen for both surface diagnostic and repair:

- it can sometimes fix sectors which were mistakingly marked as bad (soft "bad"s)
- it finds other read errors (sectors with long read time for example)
- it works with [host protected area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area) which used on some non Apple notebooks
- it allows to erase whole disk or only areas with slow access time (which sometimes 'heals' them)
- it allows to
- during surface scan it shows access time:

[image: MHDD main screen]

But it has some serious issues:

- it's dos utility so it's tricky to use on Mac ([but it's possible](http://randomcomputerbits.blogspot.com/2008/02/tutorial-installing-freedos-on-intel.html))
- it may not work with Intel SATA controllers,
- you may need to put the HDD in an external enclosure to make the utility see that drive.
- [latest version is dated 2006](http://www.ihdd.ru/download/software/mhdd/) and it's probably abandoned by author

Please recommend a utility which can be used to repair and check a disk (HDD, SSD, flash drive, etc.), find bad blocks and other surface problems. Can your utility check the entire disk surface, including the system partition?

---

Of course there are official warranty and authorized service centers, but software like this is always useful anyway (for example in a case of void warranty).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Drive Genius](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/drive_genius.php)

A personal favorite of mine, Drive Genius will do everything you're looking for with style. It's also used by the Apple Store folks, just so you know.

Comment: Thanks. I found that even Demo can check drive for bad sectors.

Answer (score 4):

There's also

### [Alsoft Disk Warrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/)

which can repair Mac OS disk directory corruption. It's often a useful "first step" before you go to something like Drive Genius.